# Scala Map -add new key and copy value from another key

Tags: scala, maps

Considering 2 sets of data as follows:

```
JSON1=> {
         "data": [
                  {"id": "1-abc",
                    "model": "Agile",
                    "status":"open"
                     "configuration": {     
                         "state": "running",
                          "rootVolumeSize": "0.00000",
                          "count": "2",
                          "type": "large",
                          "platform": "Linux"
                                    }
                      "stateId":"123-567"
                   }
                  ]}
   JSON2=>{
         "data": [
                  {"id": "1-abc",
                    "model": "Agile", 
                     "configuration": {     
                         "state": "running",
                          "diskSize": "0",
                          "type": "small",
                          "platform":"Windows"
                                    }
                   }
                  ]}
```

I need to compare JSON1 and JSON2 based on the 1st field `id` and if they match , I need to merge JSON1 with JSON 2 retaining the existing values in JSON2( only append fields not present).

I have coded the same as below:

```
private def merger(JSON1: Seq[JSON], JSON2: Seq[JSON]):Seq[JSON] = {
  val abcKey = JSON1.groupBy(_.id) map { case (k, v) => (k, v.head) 
  val mergedRecords = for {
    xyzJSON<- JSON2
  } yield (
    abcKey.get(xyzJSON.id) match {
      case Some(JSON1) => xyzJSON.copy(status = JSON1.status, 
                                       stateId = JSON1.stateId)
      case None => xyzJSON.copy(origin = "N/A")
    }
  )
```

I am not able to derive at a solution for reconciling the fields within the `configuration`Map.
Expected result set should be like:

```
         {
         "data": [
              {"id": "1-abc",
                "model": "Agile",
                "status":"open"
                 "configuration": {     
                     "state": "running",
                     "diskSize": "0",
                     "rootVolumeSize": "0.00000",
                     "count": "2",
                     "type": "small",
                     "platform": "Windows",
                                }
                  "stateId":"123-567"
               }
              ]}
```

Comment: I have arrived at a solution.Its working now